# How to rotate all images 90 degrees in a directory and all sub-directories (using mogrify)?

Tags: directory, mogrify

I'm attempting to do as my question title indicates, here is my best attempt so far:

```
find . -name '*.jpeg' -exec mogrify -rotate 90 '*.jpeg' {} +
```

This seems to rotate the images in the current directory and sub-directories 90 degrees clockwise (put a negative sign in front of the 90 and it will do counter-clockwise), but I get this error:

```
mogrify-im6.q16: unable to open image `*.jpeg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2874.
```

I'm not sure if this matters but it certainly isn't reassuring.  I'm aware that to list all `.jpeg`s within a directory and sub-directories is:

```
find . -name '*.jpeg'
```

and the basic syntax of `exec` is:

```
-exec command {} +
```

so the above apparently isn't quite right, can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?  I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 if that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out, the trick is that after the 1st `'.jpeg'` the files already found so there is no need to provide the 2nd `'.jpeg'`.

For reference:

To recursively rotate `jpeg` images 90 degrees clockwise:

```
find . -name '*.jpeg' -exec mogrify -rotate 90 {} +
```

To recursively rotate `jpeg` images 90 degrees counter-clockwise:

```
find . -name '*.jpeg' -exec mogrify -rotate -90 {} +
```